# In .htaccess same domain redirection except one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a domain and want to redirect it to other directory. Like - I want www.xyz.com to redirect to www.xyz.com/a. But not for www.xyz.com/b, it should open as www.xyz.com/b. I tried many but not got required result.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `.htaccess` with the following content:

`RewriteEngine Off`

In the folders you want to exclude from being rewritten from `mod_rewrite` module.

Comment: where to put RewriteEngine off. I am using following block -<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

 RewriteRule ^index/$ index.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/xyz
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ (/[^\ ]*)\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ http://abc/launch/$1 [R=301,NC]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to exclude a directory from being rewritten, right? If yes, just put a empty `.htaccess` with the `RewriteEngine Off` there and that folder will be not rewritted.

Comment: there is no physical directory for URL www.xyz.com/b as site is in drupal